# Trying to find even and odd number count using reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to solve the problem below using reduce but I'm not able to get the correct count of even and odd numbers in the object.

Can someone please guide me on what's wrong with my code?

> Create a function `countBy` that accepts an array and a callback, and
> returns an object. `countBy` will iterate through the array and perform
> the callback on each element. Each return value from the callback will
> be saved as a key on the object. The value associated with each key
> will be the number of times that particular return value was returned

```
function countBy(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, nums) {
    // console.log(nums);
    let oddCount = 0
    let evenCount = 0
    console.log(nums, fn(nums))
    if(fn(nums) === "even"){
      evenCount++;
      acc['even'] = evenCount;
    } else {
      oddCount++;
      acc['odd'] = oddCount;
    }
    return acc
  }, {}, 0)
}

function evenOdd(n) {
 if (n % 2 === 0) return "even";
 else return "odd";
}

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(countBy(nums, evenOdd)); // should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }
```

Comment: Is there more to this that you didn't post? Because at face value, I don't read this as returning how many odd and even numbers there are. I read this as they want a function that counts the occurrence of each unique value in a given array.  e.g. `[1,1,2,4,4,4]` would return `{1:2,2:1,4:3}` similar to php's [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're initializing `oddCount` and `evenCount` to `0` *inside* of the `reduce` callback, so on every iteration, your

```
evenCount++;
acc['even'] = evenCount;
```

is only ever incrementing the `evenCount` or `oddCount` to `1`. Initialize the counts *outside* the callback instead, so that changes to them are persistent over multiple calls of the `reduce` callback:

```js
function countBy(arr, fn) {
  let oddCount = 0
  let evenCount = 0
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, nums) {
    // console.log(nums);
    console.log(nums, fn(nums))
    if (fn(nums) === "even") {
      evenCount++;
      acc['even'] = evenCount;
    } else {
      oddCount++;
      acc['odd'] = oddCount;
    }
    return acc
  }, {}, 0)

}

function evenOdd(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) return "even";
  else return "odd";
}
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(countBy(nums, evenOdd)); // should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }
```

Or, you might avoid outer variables entirely, by checking the value of the property already on the accumulator:

```js
const countBy = (arr, fn) => arr.reduce((acc, num) => {
  const prop = fn(num);
  acc[prop] = (acc[prop] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

function evenOdd(n) {
  if (n % 2 === 0) return "even";
  else return "odd";
}
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(countBy(nums, evenOdd)); // should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }
```

Comment: Regarding the first snippet : No, this is not how you should use `reduce`. If you do this, just use a for...of loop instead.

Comment: You do not need those variables, use counters from `acc`

Comment: @SzymonD You don't *need* them, but that's what OP's code was doing, so I'm showing how to fix it with minimal changes to OP's code. Of course it would be better to just check the property on the accumulator, as you can see in the lower snippet.

Answer (score 3):

As CertainPerformance said, you are reinitializing the variables you are using to count. Also, you are sending an extra parameter to reduce, that shouldn't be there. Reduce only takes 2 parameters.

This is how I'd go about it

```
function countBy(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, nums) {
   console.log(nums, fn(nums))
    if(fn(nums) === "even"){
      acc.even ++;
    } else {
      acc.odd ++;
    }
    return acc
  }, {odd: 0, even: 0})
}
```

This is to solve in the way you want, according to the log. If you were to follow the commands, I think it would actually look like this:

```
function countBy(arr, fn) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    let key = fn(val);
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = 1;
    } else {
      acc[key]++;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {})
}
```

Your original attempt relies on the callback function returning 'odd' or 'even' to work. This code above can work with a function returning any value

Answer (score 0):

Other than with `Array.reduce` you can also solve this in a slightly different way via `Array.forEach` and a helper function:

```js
const isEvenOrOdd = n => n % 2 ? "even" : "odd"
const propCount = (prop, obj) => obj[prop] = (obj[prop] || 0) + 1

const countBy = (arr, fn, obj={}) => {
  arr.forEach(x => propCount(isEvenOrOdd(x), obj))
  return obj
}

console.log(countBy([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], isEvenOrOdd));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a generic function for incrementing a key `k` on an object `o`

```js
const incr = k => ({ [k]: val = 0, ...o }) =>
  ({ ...o, [k]: val + 1 })
  
const incrFoo =
  incr ("foo")

console .log
  ( incrFoo ({})
    // { foo: 1 }
    
  , incrFoo ({ bar: 100 })
    // { bar: 100, foo: 1 }
    
  , incrFoo ({ foo: 3, bar: 100 })
    // { bar: 100, foo: 4 }
    
  , incr ("even") ({ odd: 2, even: 2 })
    // { odd: 2, even: 3 }
  )
```

Plug it into `reduce` and `countBy` basically writes itself -

```js
const incr = k => ({ [k]: val = 0, ...o }) =>
  ({ ...o, [k]: val + 1 })
  
const countBy = (f, xs = []) =>
  xs .reduce
    ( (acc, x) => incr (f (x)) (acc)
    , {}
    )

console .log
  ( countBy
      ( x => x & 1 ? "odd" : "even"
      , [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
      )
      // { even: 2, odd: 3 }

  , countBy
      ( x => x
      , [ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c' ]
      )
      // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
  )
```

Higher-order functions are not limited to `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` - Using a continuation combinator, `$` below, we show `countBy` as a recursive function. As an added advantage, this implementation accepts any *iterable* as an input; not only arrays.

```js
const incr = k => ({ [k]: val = 0, ...o }) =>
  ({ ...o, [k]: val + 1 })
  
const $ = x => k =>
  k (x)
  
const None =
  Symbol ()
  
const countBy = (f, [ x = None, ...xs ]) =>
  x === None
    ? {}
    : $ (f (x))
        (key => $ (countBy (f, xs)) (incr (key)))
  
console .log
  ( countBy
      ( x => x & 1 ? "odd" : "even"
      , [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
      )
      // { even: 2, odd: 3 }

  , countBy
      ( x => x
      , "mississippi"
      )
      // { p: 2, s: 4, i: 4, m: 1 }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a function to check even number like

```
const isEven = n => n%2 === 0;
```

And the initialization object result should look like

```
{odd: 0, even: 0}
```

```js
var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const isEven = n => n%2 == 0;
const result = nums.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if(isEven(curr)) acc.even++;
  else acc.odd++;
  
  return acc;  
}, {odd: 0, even: 0})
console.log(result); // should log: { odd: 3, even: 2 }
```